# Yii 2.0 Passing data from Form to Controller

Tags: php, yii2

So recently, I migrate from CodeIgniter to Yii2.0 .

I have a view form that users can view and update the data
my form looks like this :

```
<form role="form" name="damnedForm" action="">
   <div class="form-group">
        <label>SKU Code</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="pSku" value="<?= $model->sku ?>">
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
         <label>Name</label>
         <input class="form-control" name="pName" value="<?= $model->name ?>">
   </div>

   <div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit me</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

I have a controller named ProductsController, with method :

```
    function actionUpdate($id) {
      // bla bla bla // 
    }
```

My question is :

How do I pass all the data from the form to my controller? Do I have to make a manual post/get method and catch it on the controller? Or can I use the ActiveForm class ?

Answer (score 2):

// Your view for the form should be something like this exerpt

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="the-box">
            <h4 class="small-title">Create New Department</h4>
            <?php
            $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                'id' => 'department-Department-form',
                'enableClientValidation' => true,
                'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
            ));
            ?>

            <!--<form role="form">-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelDepartment, 'dept_name'); ?>
                <?php
                echo $form->textField($modelDepartment, 'dept_name', array(
                    'id' => 'dept_name',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                ));
                ?>
                <small style="color: #e9573f;"><?php echo $form->error($modelDepartment, 'dept_name'); ?>
                </small>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelDepartment, 'dept_contact'); ?>
                <?php
                echo $form->textField($modelDepartment, 'dept_contact', array(
                    'id' => 'dept_contact',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
//                        'placeholder' => 'ID Number',
                ));
                ?>
                <small style="color: #e9573f;"><?php echo $form->error($modelDepartment, 'dept_contact'); ?>
                </small>
            </div>




            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelDepartment, 'dept_hod'); ?>
                <?php
                echo $form->dropDownList($modelDepartment, 'dept_hod', $employeeList, $htmlOptions = array(
                    'class' => 'form-control chosen-select'
                ));
                ?>

                <small style="color: #e9573f;"><?php echo $form->error($modelDepartment, 'dept_hod'); ?>
                </small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelDepartment, 'dept_email'); ?>
                <?php
                echo $form->textField($modelDepartment, 'dept_email', array(
                    'id' => 'dept_email',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
//                        'placeholder' => 'ID Number',
                ));
                ?>
                <small style="color: #e9573f;"><?php echo $form->error($modelDepartment, 'dept_email'); ?>
                </small>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Create</button>
            <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
            <!--</form>-->
        </div><!-- /.the-box -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="the-box">
            <?php
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($dtData);
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
//Your Model should be something like this format
class DepartmentForm extends CFormModel {

    public $dept_name;
    public $dept_contact;
    public $dept_hod;
    public $dept_email;

    public function rules() {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('dept_name, dept_contact, dept_hod, dept_email', 'required'),
            array('dept_hod', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
            array('dept_name, dept_contact', 'length', 'max' => 255),
            array('dept_email', 'length', 'max' => 150),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('dept_id, dept_name, dept_contact, dept_hod, dept_email', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
        );
    }

    public function attributeLabels() {
        return array(
            'dept_id' => 'Dept',
            'dept_name' => 'Department Name',
            'dept_contact' => 'Department Contact',
            'dept_hod' => 'Department HOD',
            'dept_email' => 'Department Email',
        );
    }

}
//Your Controller should be something like this
public function actionManageDepartments() {

        $modelDept = new DepartmentForm(); //Initialize the model above
        $sql = new TSqlResource();


        //Handles the Work Profile
        if (Yii::app()->request->getPost('DepartmentForm')) {
            $modelDept->attributes = Yii::app()->request->getPost('DepartmentForm');
            if ($modelDept->validate()) {
                $data = array(
//                    dept_name, dept_contact, dept_hod, dept_email
                    'dept_name' => $modelDept->attributes ['dept_name'],
                    'dept_contact' => $modelDept->attributes ['dept_contact'],
                    'dept_hod' => $modelDept->attributes ['dept_hod'],
                    'dept_email' => $modelDept->attributes ['dept_email'],
                    'created_by' => Yii::app()->session['user']['profile_id'],
                );
                //insert into database
                $dataSql = $sql->postDepartment($data);

                if ($dataSql == true) {
                    YII::app()->user->setFlash('alert alert-success', ' Successfully Created <strong>' . $data['dept_name'] . '</strong>  Department. ');
                } else {
                    YII::app()->user->setFlash('alert alert-danger', 'Sorry  an Error Occured while adding <strong>' . $data['dept_name'] . '</strong> Department. Contact Admin for assistance ');
                }
            }
        }
//        #end work profile post
        $this->render('manageDepartments', array(
            'modelDepartment' => $modelDept,
            'dtData' => $dtData,
                )
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already know, Yii2 comes with a fantastic gode-generator tool called Gii. You can access it with `index.php?r=gii` as long as you are in `dev` environment.

If you use this tool to create a CRUD for your model, you can look in the code how the forms are written and collected in the views and controller.

I recommend this approach, as its the "yii-way" of doing forms.

Welcome to Yii!

Comment: I have read and used Gii, my forms are generated by it, but what I want to do is I want to change it and design my form manually not by using  auto form rendering that yii provides

Comment: I dont know why you would do that, but then you have to use normal php to gather your data in the action, and assign it to the attribute in the model `$model->yourAttribute = $_POST['yourFormElementId']`. Edit: i cant stress the value of doing things the way yii intended enough. If you write it yourself you will not have validation feedback in your form, it takes more time, and its not as safe.